# Does a function with two frequencies have a special name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, terminology

Consider a real function of the form $f(x) = A \cos(x) + B \cos(2x)$.   Does this type of function have a special name? At first, I thought it could be bi-periodic, or bi-harmonic, or doubly-periodic, but I see that these terms are already used for other kinds of functions.

Comment: The situation depends a lot on whether the periods are commensurate, i.e. rational multiples of each other, or not. Here they are commensurate, so the sum actually has period $2\pi$.

Comment: You could call this a dichromatic wave.

Comment: No special name.

Answer (score 1):

The function is still just periodic. With period $2\pi$.